# "application defined or object defined error" while trying to create a table

Tags: excel, vba

basically what the headline says,
im getting an "application defined or object defined error"
and i cant figure out what did i do wrong.

thanks

```
Dim lastR As Long
Dim lastC As Long
Dim StartCell As Range
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Activate
Set StartCell = Range("A1")
'Find Last Row and Column
  lastR = Cells(Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
'Select Range
 Dim table As ListObject
Set table = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(StartCell, "H" & lastR), xlYes)
Dim lastR1 As Long
Dim StartCell1 As Range
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Activate
Set StartCell1 = Range("A1")
'Find Last Row and Column
lastR1 = Cells(Rows.Count, StartCell1.Column).End(xlUp).Row
'Select Range
 Dim table1 As ListObject
Set table1 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(StartCell1, "H" & lastR1), xlYes)
```

Comment: Did you step into the code and see at which line the error occurs?

Comment: i tried but couldnt..it wont let me debug it

Comment: *"Turn it off and on again"* :P. Seriously do it and try again to step into the code

Comment: I ran this code, with values in the 2nd and 3rd sheets (index wise), and have data in Column A, and it works great. Do you have other settings ?

Comment: its inside of a button sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apperantly the problem was that i created an Active X button and inserted the code there..

worked with a regular button